# Swift Invalid Base64 - String Concatenation

Tags: ios, swift

All,

This is kind of a two part question...

First, I am attempting to base 64 encode an image:

```
    var finalMessage = "";
    if(imageBytes != nil && imageBytes.length > 0){
        finalMessage += " <image>";
        finalMessage += imageBytes!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil);
        finalMessage += "</image>";
    }
```

When I debug and inspect `finalMessage` after the last concatenation setter, I have this as the value in the debugger:

```
"\U0000fffc <image>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"
```

Its a long one, so scroll all the way right to see that there is no `</image>` tag that is seen in line 6 of the code above. Very strange....

So, is there a size limit on base 64 encoding? Any idea of what might be going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try a `println(finalMessage)`? The *debugger* might limit the output to a certain length.

Comment: @MartinR: you were right, it was the debugger. I will need to provide more details on the second question... so, if you add your response I can mark this solved.

Comment: Just to close the loop, the other issue was database field length truncation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no size limit on Base64 encoded strings other than your available
memory. In particular there is no reason why the second statement in

```
    finalMessage += imageBytes!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil);
    finalMessage += "</image>";
```

should do nothing. But the *debugger* might limit the output (perhaps to
64K?), so when in doubt, check with `NSLog()` or `println()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var finalString = ""
let screenshot = UIImage(named: "screen")
let screenshotData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshot)
let screenshotBase64 = screenshotData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength) as NSString

if (screenshotBase64 != "") {
    let tempString = screenshotBase64.stringByAppendingString("</image>")
    finalString = "<image>\(tempString)"
}

println(finalString)
```

Replace "screen" with whatever your image name is and check if this works.

Comment: This code is assuming you're working with PNG images as well.

Comment: I am using the equivalent method for JPEGs with a compression parameter of .20.